# Transforming directed network into undirected while preserving degree distribution

Tags: r, graph, bioconductor

I have a directed network where 50 nodes have a degree of 3 and another 50 have a degree of 10.

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("graph")

#load graph and make the specified graph
library(graph)
degrees=c(rep(3,50),rep(10,50))
names(degrees)=paste("node",seq_along(degrees)) #nodes must be names
x=randomNodeGraph(degrees)

#verify graph
edges=edgeMatrix(x)
edgecount=table(as.vector(edges))
table(edgecount)
```

This is a directed network where the total degree is made up from both indegree and outdegree.

I would like to have a network where every indegree is also an outdegree and vice versa

so for example if `node 1` has an edge to `node 5` then `node 5` also needs to have an edge to `node 1`. My main goal is to preserve the degree distribution, i.e. 50 with degree of 3 and 50 with degree of 10.

Answer (score 0):

Simply setting the graph to be undirected seems to do it:

```
x2 <- x
edgemode(x2) <- "undirected"
edges<-edgeMatrix(x)
edgecount <- table(as.vector(edges))
table(edgecount)
```

Gives the same results as your code. 
Also, an undirected graph will always have an edge from 5 to 1 if there is an edge from 1 to 5. A single edge satisfies this property.

Comment: the third line of your code seems to have a mistake, you mean edges<-edgeMatrix(x2), right? if you change it to x2 you no longer get the same results, the degree distribution is broken.

Comment: Oops. I'll try and find you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Paul Shannon suggests the following:

```
library(graph)
library(igraph)
degrees=c(rep(3,50),rep(10,50))
g <- igraph.to.graphNEL(degree.sequence.game(degrees))
table(graph::degree(g))
```

This gives the same results as your code.